# Bash: Passing a variable as argument with quotes

Tags: bash, shell, emacs24

I'm trying to pass some arguments to ecb. But I think theres an issue with the escaping of quotes. The $edir variable below particularly is giving a lot of issues.

```
#!/bin/bash

edir='"(open-project-ecb \"'`pwd`'\")"'

#edir=`pwd`

echo $edir

command=( -n --eval $edir)

emacsclient "${command[@]}"
```

Comment: How do you exactly want to have `pwd` surrounded?

Comment: @fedorqui so in an ideal world "(open-project-ecb \"pwd\")"

Comment: That's what I get if I perform your command. `echo $edir` gives me `"(open-project-ecb \"/my/dir\")"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just quoting too soon. As long as you quote the expansion of `$edir`, you don't need to embed extra quotes in its value; it will be treated as a single word.

```
edir="(open-project-ecb \"$(pwd)\")"
command=( -n --eval "$edir" )
emacsclient "${command[@]}"
```

Comment: Awesome works! I would vote you up but I don't have enough reputation apparently.

Comment: @bobarillo did that for you